# Where Are the Azure Active Directory Application Certificates?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sdk-.net

I am exploring [this great sample application](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-certificate-credential) on how to use Azure Active Directory applications.

In it, [it describes a process to upload a certificate](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-certificate-credential) to use with the registered application.

My question is: where are these certificates stored, and are they accessible from the portal?  Furthermore, if I upload an application manifest without the entry, does it delete the certificate from my Azure Active Directory account?  Or does the entry itself get deleted from my Azure Active Directory application?  Or both?

Thank you in advance for any assistance and/or clarification.